# remove oh-my-zsh

Tags: osx, zsh, oh-my-zsh

I have installed [oh-my-zsh](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh) on `high Sierra` but cannot uninstall and return my terminal to standard bash.
I have used `uninstall_oh_my_zsh`command, but still can see *.zsh* on terminal once open it!
can anyone help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should change your terminal to bash first using `/usr/bin/chsh -s /bin/bash` , then simply remove all `zsh` related files. Or use this [Script](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/blob/master/tools/uninstall.sh)  to run it simply navigate to the script directory and  do `sh uninstall.sh`

Comment: I'm new to script. can you please give me a brief instruction on how can I run this Script ?

Comment: sh scriptname.sh